# How to conditionally render with a redux array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a form that I am building for a user to create a homework assignment. I have a drop-down of classes for them to select in the form, but I only want to show the drop-down if they have any classes, stored as `this.props.classes`. In the past, I have been able to conditionally render certain components with state, but it is not working now when I try to do it with props.

How I am trying to do it:

```
{ this.props.classes !== [] && //I still see it even if it's an empty array
  <View style={{ flex: 1, bottom: 20 }}> //doesn't work with the !== check or without
    <Dropdown
      label='Class'
      baseColor='#fcefef'
      data={this.props.classes}
      valueExtractor={(value) => value.name}
      onChangeText={formikProps.handleChange('class')}
      dropdownPosition={-2}
    />
 </View>
}
```

If anyone could show how it would be possible to get the behavior I am expecting it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because arrays are reference types in JavaScript. Actually does not matter if `this.props.classes` is an empty array, it will never equal to `[]` since it's a new Array instance.

**Solution**: You could simply check if the length of `classes` equals to `0`.

```
{this.props.classes.length !== 0 && ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.props.classes.length !== 0
```